# Greensock - TypeError: Cannot set property 'startAt' of undefined

Tags: gsap

I'm a newb fiddling with Greensock on Codepen and it's already not being my friend. The error I'm getting is "TypeError: Cannot set property 'startAt' of undefined". I've read the docs and looked at other examples, but I'm not seeing it. I do believe I'm successfully importing the Greensock CDN in the settings also. Who knows?

Here's a link to the Codepen, but I'll include the super basic code below.

https://codepen.io/kscarabello/pen/mXbBGm

HTML code:

```
<h1 id='text'>Hi there</h1>
```

JavaScript code:

```
let text = document.getElementById('text')

TweenMax.fromTo(text, 5, {width: 100px, height: 500px}, {width: 200px, height: 100px})
```

Comment: you probably need to get rid of those `px` suffixes from your `width` and `height` values from within the `fromTo` calls i.e. make it like so:

`TweenMax.fromTo(text, 5, { width: 100, height: 500 }, { width: 200, height: 100 });`

Comment: I appreciate you so much! Worked beautifully! Thanks.